# using concatenation on c#

Tags: c#, winforms, concatenation, desktop-application

What is the correct way to concatenate these elements?

Environment: C#-WinForm-Desktop.

In my app, I have a text file called `config.ini`. This file has values with this nomenclature:

> csv_month_hour=value

The data are thus:

```
[csv]
csv_01_01=value // 24 hours a day in January
csv_01_02=value 
csv_01_03=value 
.
csv_02_01=value // 24 hours a day in February
csv_02_02=value 
csv_02_03=value 
.
// and so on
```

My app has this method called:

```
private void getMonthHour()
{
    DateTime Xdt = DateTime.Now;
    int Xmonth = Xdt.Month;
    int Xhour = Xdt.Hour;

    if (File.Exists("config.ini"))
    {
        IniFile ini = new IniFile("config.ini");

        m3h = Convert.ToDouble(confg.csv["csv_" + Xmonth.ToString + "_" + Xhour.ToString]);
    }
}
```

This method is called every seconds in `timer_tick` to check the month and time to use the corresponding value.

I need to know how to concatenate this:
    m3h = Convert.ToDouble(confg.csv["csv_"+Xmonth.ToString+"_"+Xhour.ToString]);

An example of the code would be:

```
if (Xmonth==1&&Xhour==1){m3h = Convert.ToDouble(confg.csv.csv_01_01);}
else if (Xmonth==1&&Xhour==2){m3h = Convert.ToDouble(confg.csv.csv_01_02);}  
else if (Xmonth==1&&Xhour==3){m3h = Convert.ToDouble(confg.csv.csv_01_03);}
// csv_month_hour in this case 01 is January.
else if (Xmonth==2&&Xhour==1){m3h = Convert.ToDouble(confg.csv.csv_02_01);}
// And so on, until December (12).
```

Comment: You have not said what the problem is...

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide an example input and output.

Comment: Is there any problem ?

Comment: Putting aside the invalid syntax/compiler error from your method calls in your code, I suspect you're building the string but can't get the leading `0` in front of digits 0-9. Try using `Xmonth.ToString("00")` and `Xhour.ToString("00")`

Comment: Please edit your question so as to actually ask the question. What is your desired input-output?

Comment: Is my config.ini file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting aside the invalid syntax/compiler error from your method calls in your code, I suspect you're building the string but can't get the leading `0` in front of digits 0-9. So when `Xmonth` and `Xhour` are less than 10, your string is being built as `"csv_1_1"` instead of your intended `"csv_01_01"`.

To instruct the `ToString` method to include a leading zero when needed, you can supply a [custom numeric format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `"00"` (see the first entry in the link for "Zero placeholder").

Try using `Xmonth.ToString("00")` and `Xhour.ToString("00")`:

```
Monitor.malyt.m3h = Convert.ToDouble(confg.csv["csv_" + 
    Xmonth.ToString("00") + "_" + 
    Xhour.ToString("00")]);
```

This will output the values of `Xmonth` and `Xhour` with a single leading zero where needed.

Comment: Returns a error message that "..confg.csv" is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context

Comment: @user981650: We've answered your question how to _concatenate_ the string to produce the text "csv_01_01" (and the like). If you want to find out how to _read_ the data your config file, please mark this question as answered and open a new question asking _how_ to read the file. Before opening a new question, I suggest you take a look at the `File.ReadAllLines` method (to read each line of your config) and `String.Split` method (to separate the `csv_01_01` keys from their `=value` values). If you have issues at that point, post a question _specifically_ about that.